# Spring Boot 3 application rewrites URL to actual jsp path

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, jsp, tomcat

I'm working on a Spring Boot 3 application and I have the following problem:

When trying to access localhost:8080/event I get redirected to the actual path of the jsp like here: localhost:8080/WEB-INF/jsp/eventDetailPage.jsp?continue

This is my controller:

```
@Controller
public class EventController {
 @GetMapping(path = "/event")
 public ModelAndView getEvent(Model model) {
    return new ModelAndView("eventDetailPage");
 }
}
```

I debugged it and the `getEvent()` method gets executed. But after that I get redirected to the jsp location with a 404. And the redirect/rewrite happens only when I'm not logged in however the controller also gets called when I'm logged out since I whitelisted the url pattern in my WebSecurityConfig.

I've only worked with Spring Boot 1 & 2 before, this must have something to do with changes in version 3.

These are the dependencies from my pom.xml:

```
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.h2database</groupId>
        <artifactId>h2</artifactId>
        <scope>runtime</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-security-test</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-autoconfigure</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.embed</groupId>
        <artifactId>tomcat-embed-jasper</artifactId>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>jakarta.servlet.jsp.jstl</groupId>
        <artifactId>jakarta.servlet.jsp.jstl-api</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.0</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

I also have the following application.properties: `spring.mvc.view.prefix=/WEB-INF/jsp/` &
`spring.mvc.view.suffix=.jsp`

Comment: Now only missing link: where is the jsp? (In src/deployed)

Comment: @xerx593 it's in src/main/WEB-INF/jsp

Comment: no, better: `src/main/resources/WEB-INF/jsp` (assuming maven|gradle defaults)

Comment: @xerx593 unfortunately the rewrite still happens regardless of the jsp location